# Ruby On Rails - Resque Scheduler - More frequently between certain hours

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scheduled-tasks, yaml, resque

I'm new to rails scheduler but have managed to setup a task.

I wonder if it's possible to set it up so it do a certain task more frequently between working hours than the other hours?

Like.

Between 07:30 - 21: 00 repeat the task every 2 minutes.

Between 21:00 - 07:30 repeat the task every 1 hour.

This is my code so far resque_schedule.yml

```
do_the_job:
  every: 2m
  class: foo
  args: bar
  description: baz
```

But as you can see it repeats the task every 2 minutes and doesn't care about the time at all.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add the cron settings to your files

```
 do_the_job: 
   cron: "* * * * *" # change this according to your need 
   every: 2m
   class: foo
   args: bar
   description: baz
```

To add timings to cron check this http://www.adminschoice.com/crontab-quick-reference

Hope this helps